# DiscordJs & distube - Why can't I do anything after I play music?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, distube

I am using DiscordJs and distube to create a bot for my discord server. I am using slash commands. The problem is that I can't execute any command (so I cannot even execute /stop or play another song) after I play a song. This is my code:

```js
const {SlashCommandBuilder} = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("Play a song.")
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName("song").setDescription("The song link or name.").setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.reply({content: 'Music started.', ephemeral: true});
        const {member, channel, client} = interaction;
        await client.distube.play(member.voice.channel, interaction.options.get("song").value, {textChannel: channel, member: member});
    }
}
```

My command handler:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');

const clientId = '12345678';
const guildId = '12345678';

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async (commandsFolder, path) => {
        client.commandArray = [];
        for (const folder of commandsFolder) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${path}/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                await client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                client.commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
            }
        }
        const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken("sometextthatidontwanttoshow");

        await (async () => {
            try {
                console.log('Started refreshing application commands.');

                await rest.put(
                    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
                    {body: client.commandArray},
                );

                console.log('Successfully reloaded application commands.');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })();
    }
}
```

And this is the function that "creates" the commands:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (!command) return;
        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({
                content: "There was an error while executing this command.",
                ephemeral: true
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my index file

```js
const {Client, Intents, Collection} = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES]});
client.commands = new Collection();

const {DisTube} = require("distube");
client.distube = new DisTube(client, {
    emitNewSongOnly: true,
    leaveOnFinish: false,
    emitAddSongWhenCreatingQueue: false
});
module.exports = client;

const functions = fs.readdirSync("./src/functions").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/events").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const commandsFolders = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands");

(async () => {
    for (const file of functions) {
        require(`./src/functions/${file}`)(client);
    }
    client.handleEvents(eventFiles, "./src/events");
    client.handleCommands(commandsFolders, "./src/commands");
    await client.login('mybeautifultoken')
})();
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your event + command listener look like? This may be an asynchronous issue where this asynchronous function is being used synchronously

Comment: Great, this is where the commands are being registered to discord for your bot. Could you also post your event listener? That will be where you will be listening for the slash command to 'execute'

Comment: @tempnameenjoyer updated again, sorry, I forgot to put it before.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I believe the issue lies in the fact that you're awaiting your command.execute(). I believe behind the scenes what this is doing is that its creating a promise that resolves once your discord bot's music finishes playing.

While its correct to use these functions asynchronously, when you call it like this it actually blocks all the other similar asynchronous functions (slash commands) from occurring until this one resolves. Let me know if this fixes it.

```
module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (!command) return;
        try {
            command.execute(interaction); //removed await
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({
                content: "There was an error while executing this command.",
                ephemeral: true
            })
        }
    }
}
```

index edits

```
 await client.handleEvents(eventFiles, "./src/events");
 await client.handleCommands(commandsFolders, "./src/commands");
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I really don't know why.

Comment: Hmm okay. How does your index.js look? Specifically where we are listening for the interactions

Comment: I just updated the post

Comment: I know we're just throwing await at things now but let me know if this change in the extra snippet in the answer works

Comment: Do I need to await them?

Comment: That might be the case. The function is asynchronous but those calls to handle the commands are not.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242127/discussion-between-tempnameenjoyer-and-elpideus).